# uninitialized constant TimelistsController::Timelistとなる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ネットで調べると原因はファイル名とクラス名の不一致と書いてあるのですが、ファイル名が `timelists_controller.rb` でコードは以下の通りでクラス名と一致しています。解決方法を教えてください。

```rb
class TimelistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user_logged_in
  def index
    @timelists =  Timelist.all
  end
  def create
    @timelist = Timelist.new(time_params)
    if @timelist.save
      flash.now[:success] = "投稿しました。"
      render "toppages/index"
    else
      
      flash.now[:danger] = "投稿できませんでした。"
      render "toppages/index"
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    @timelist = Timelist.find(params[:id])
    @timelist.destroy
    
    flash.now[:success] = "行動を記録しました。"
    render "times.index"
  end
  
  def time_params
    params.require(:timemanagement).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

Comment: Timelist クラスはモデルのように使われていますが、`app/models` 以下に当該ファイルは存在していますか?

Answer (score 1):

`TimelistsController` クラス内のメソッドで `Timelist` を参照していますが、それがどこにも定義されていないために、`uninitialized constant` になっています。

`TimelistsController` 配下で `Timelist` が定義されるか、またはトップレベルで定義されていればエラーにはなりません。